TypeError: Failed to fetch en JavaScript para obtener datos de una API
Estoy intentando obtener datos de una API usando fetch en JavaScript, pero no estoy recibiendo los datos esperados. En lugar de los datos, estoy recibiendo un error. Aquí está mi código:


fetch('https://api.example.com/data')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));



Espero que la consola muestre los datos obtenidos de la API, pero en su lugar, obtengo el siguiente error:

Error: TypeError: Failed to fetch**

He revisado la URL y parece correcta. También he probado con diferentes endpoints de la API y sigo obteniendo el mismo error. ¿Qué podría estar causando este problema y cómo puedo solucionarlo?
Detalles adicionales:
Estoy ejecutando este código en el navegador.
La API requiere autenticación, pero he añadido el token de autorización en el encabezado de la solicitud.
He verificado que la API está en funcionamiento probándola en Postman.
Aquí está la versión completa de mi código con la autorización:


fetch('https://api.example.com/data', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer mi-token-de-autorizacion',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));



¿Hay algo que esté haciendo mal o algo que deba considerar para que fetch funcione correctamente con esta API?

si el codigo es talcual el que estas usando... el error es la url: https://api.example.com/data

po otro lado si la url no es esa y es una que esta correcta, puede ser un problema de cors o authenticacion o headers ... etc ... sin un ejemplo minimo funcional (que permita replicar el error) se complica el poder ayudarte ...
